# "numerical rounding" in view or in model?

Tags: model-view-controller, view, model, standards, rounding

Maybe that's a stupid question, but i'm totally unsure about how "intelligent" a view should be:

**Is it good practice to round a number in the view (or is it a no-go and you have to do it in the model) ?**

Rounding is usually a layout/output thing, but also a mathematical issue which belongs into a model. Hm....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like the idea of rounding at the last possible moment in the view, since there are many quantities such as money that will be displayed using two decimal points, but that require more precision when performing calculations (although money is a bad example since you probably want to use exact integer arithmetic, but you get the idea).